# nestjs+Typeorm put initial data when sync

Tags: initialization, nestjs, typeorm

I am working on a project using typeorm and nestjs.

When a table is first created, I want to execute the sql statement and put the data in it.

I searched for a way to put the initial data, but couldn't find any results.

I need your help.
thank you :)

Comment: Why not make it a part of the migration for the table?

Comment: I'm not sure what migration means.

Comment: [migrations](https://typeorm.io/migrations) are commands ran by the ORM framework (or query-builder in the case of knex and kysely) that instruct the framework how to build the database step by step. Usually used to help modify the database after certain build steps have been made as well

Comment: thank you. I will study migration of typeorm.